# Generate alphanumeric sequence in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

How would I go about generating a sequential alphanumeric string?

Each string should only be 8 characters.

The characters possible for each position are:

```
["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

Also, If possible I would like to choose the starting point of the sequence.

For example:

```
00000001
00000002
00000003
00000005
...
0000L3FH
0000L3FJ
0000L3FK
0000L3FL
0000L3FM
0000L3FN
0000L3FP
...
0000L4FP
0000L4FQ
0000L4FR
0000L4FS
...
0000M000
0000M001
0000M002
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is a permutation with repetition. Arrays can do that out of the box.

```
chars = %w(0 1 2 B C)
sequencer = chars.repeated_permutation(chars.size) #OP:replace chars.size by 8
10.times{p sequencer.next}
#["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
#["0", "0", "0", "0", "1"]
#["0", "0", "0", "0", "2"]
#["0", "0", "0", "0", "B"]
#["0", "0", "0", "0", "C"]
#["0", "0", "0", "1", "0"]
#["0", "0", "0", "1", "1"]
#["0", "0", "0", "1", "2"]
#["0", "0", "0", "1", "B"]
#["0", "0", "0", "1", "C"]

p sequencer.next
#["0", "0", "0", "2", "0"]
```

Comment: very good answer and completely obsoletes mine. Learned yet another new thing in ruby :)

Comment: I don't think so. Added another answer where it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This one allows for setting the starting point:

```
dial = %w(0 1 2 A B)
start_position = %w(A B 0) #for instance.

p clock = start_position.map{|char| dial.rotate(dial.index(char))}
#[["A","B","0","1","2"], ["B","0","1","2","A"], ["0","1","2","A","B"]]

# start ticking:
clock.shift.product(*clock){|tick|p tick}
#["A", "B", "0"]
#["A", "B", "1"]
#["A", "B", "2"]
#["A", "B", "A"]
#["A", "B", "B"]
#["A", "0", "0"]
#...
```

Comment: Where can I find documentation on the dup method on line 4 in the block?

Comment: @tester123 Made it shorter (and dup-less).

Comment: Cute, but this will generate all possibilities (e.g 000), which I don't think is what is required

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune Do you mean stopping just before ['0', '0', '0'] ?